# kubernetes - how to find pods that are running and ready?

Tags: kubernetes

I'd like to get the list of kubernetes pods for a service that are "Running" and fully "Ready".

And by fully ready, I mean shows a full "READY" count in k9s, so if there are 4 conditions for the pod to run, I see "READY" with "4/4" listed in k9s.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a particular service, `my-service`, this only shows pods that are fully ready

```
$ kubectl get pods --selector=app=my-service -o json  | select_ready_pods.py
```

Similar idea for all pods

```
$ kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o json  | select_ready_pods.py
```

List pods that are NOT ready

```
$ kubectl get pods --selector=app=my-service -o json  | select_ready_pods.py --not_ready
```

### select_ready_pods.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import json

try:
    a = json.load(sys.stdin)
except:
    print("The data from stdin doesnt appear to be valid json. Fix this!")
    sys.exit(1)


def main(args):
    for i in a['items']:
        length = len(i['status']['conditions'])
        count = 0
        for j in i['status']['conditions']:
            if (j['status'] == "True"):
                count=count+1

        if (args.not_ready):
            if (count != length):
                print(i['metadata']['name'])
        else:
            if (count == length):
                print(i['metadata']['name'])

import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--not_ready", help="show pods that are NOT ready", action="store_true")
args = parser.parse_args()

main(args)
```

Comment: maybe it's also useful to say that if you'd like to print out all pods which have one of their conditions set to "False" you just have to change `if (count == length):` to `if (count != length):`

can take you a little while to figure that out if you're not that used to work with arrays and stuff like this, other than that great answer!

Comment: @alex - good idea! I've added what I think should work for your use case, an option to show the nodes that aren't ready